# Going to last drive present in the system instead going to one that i selected

Tags: c#

In my project I want to send the the name of drive that is clicked to the next page.But it is sending the name of the last drive that is present in my system instead of sending the name of drive that i clicked.Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace listofdirectories
{
    public partial class directories : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string str1;
        LinkButton lnk; 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] drives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string str in drives)
            {
                lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = str;
                lnk.ID = i.ToString();
                this.Panel1.Controls.Add(lnk);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_Click);
                i++;
                str1 = lnk.Text;
            }        
        }

        protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("files.aspx?drive="+str1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the single variable that is set again and again. Just get the text from the event:

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as LinkButton;
    Response.Redirect("files.aspx?drive=" + button.Text);
}
```